# jRuby gem in a jar generates directory instead of jar

Tags: java, rubygems, jruby

I'm using jruby and have been putting my gems in a jar like this

`java -jar jruby_complete.jar -S gem install -i gem_jar.jar nokogiri erubis`

This creates a jar "file" and correctly installs the gems. I can add this jar "file" to my search path and my project will run, however when I go to do a distribution build in netbeans, it complains about the gem_jar being a directory.

A .jar is just a zipped directory, or so I thought, so I ran

```
zip gem_jar.zip gem_jar; mv gem_jar.jar gem_jar.old; mv gem_jar.zip gem_jar.jar
```

Netbeans no longer complains, but the project won't run. How have I failed at coercing my gem jar into an actual compressed jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `-i` flag on jruby is not creating a jar. That was a false assumption on my part. The correct method is this

```
java -jar jruby_complete.jar -S gem install -i gem_jar nokogiri erubis
jar cf gem_jar.jar -C gem_jar .
```